# How can I troubleshoot keyboard shortcuts that are not working?

Tags: keyboard, macos, mission-control

Within system preferences --> keyboard --> shortcuts --> mission control I have the following shortcut set:

[image]

I record the shortcut by hitting <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>, but when I play the shortcut back, I am not able to actually move to that space.

When showing my desktops I see that I have Desktops 1-5 as well.

How can I troubleshoot why this specific shortcut is not working? I have a similar shortcut for <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> to move to Desktop 4, which does work.

This feels like a trivial problem but I do not know how to actually investigate much. I have used an application called Karabiner to verify the OS is processing the keystrokes correctly:

[image]

But the shortcut does not move me to Desktop 5.

Comment: Does _anything_ happen when you use Control+5? It's probably conflicting with another shortcut somewhere, though it's usually pretty good about notifying you to conflicts.

Comment: Do you have a 10-key [num-pad] or a 'short' keyboard? 10-key's numbers  are recognised differently to the ones above qwerty. By default, the shortcuts assigned to Spaces are the qwerty ones.

Comment: No and no. Interestingly, my system helpfully restarted for other reasons and the issue went away... :\